# Display Same data in row and column in asp.net gridview from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63YiW.png)Display Same data in row and column in asp.net gridview from codebehind ?

Comment: Please provide example.

Comment: Please see image description

Comment: You have a single row in the original result??

Comment: Yes Only Single row

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question but try this.

```
    //Create your Original DataSource
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("col1");
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("col2");
    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("col3");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "A";
    dr[01] = "B";
    dr[2] = "C";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    //Adding Rows
    for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = dt.Rows[0][i].ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
    }
    GridViewName.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewName.DataBind();
```